# Using TScrollBox to Contain TExpander components

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tscrollbox

Well i have one scrollbox aligned to left of my form, inside the scrollbox i have TExpander components aligned to Top, this expanders exceed the area of the scrollbox so i guess the scrollbars must be visibles but they aren't. 
I think the problem is with the aligned on top of the Texpanders because if i change the alignment of the Texpander ho are exceeding the margins of the scrollbox to alNone the scrollbars apear, but i need to have the Texpander aligned on top because his constatly size changing. Any ideas? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have no idea why it worked, but set the '**TExpander.Align**' to '**alTop**', and then set '**TExpander.Anchors**' to:

```
akLeft = True
akTop = True
akRight = False
akBottom = False
```

Worked for me ;)

Comment: Yes! that works fine.. The Anchors at right was the problems.. Thanks a lot!